# Unexpected entity related to newly created

Tags: android, orm, greendao

In my Android application I am using GreenDao as an orm.

I have two tables: `A` and `B`. Table `B` has foreign key to table `A`.
`A` entities can execute `getBList()` method and `B` entities can execute `getA()` method.

When I started to remove some `A` entities with connected `B` entities from database I noted strange behavior. Now some of newly created `A` entities have connected `B` entities, but there is no connecting in code:

```
A a = new A();
// setting some simple a fields, nothing with Bs
aDao.create(a);
a.getBList(); // not empty list
```

Does anybody know what can cause such behavior and how to fix it?

Comment: Sounds like somehow the references are getting recycled and you are not removing or rewriting B so they become attached to different objects? I am not sure about how they are referencing each other in your database. I'd suggest detaching A from B before removing A.

Answer (score 0):

This is from the [greenDao website](http://greendao-orm.com/documentation/relations/):

> ### Resolving and Updating To-Many Relations
>
> To-many relations are resolved lazily on the first request. After
>   that, the related entities are cached in the source entity inside a
>   List object. Subsequent calls to the get method of the relation do not
>   query the database.
>
> Note that updating to-many relations require some additional work.
>   Because to-many lists are cached, they are not updated when related
>   entities are added to the database. The following code illustrates the
>   behavior:
>
> ```
> List orders1 = customer.getOrders();
> int size1 = orders1.size();
>
> Order order = new Order();
> order.setCustomerId(customer.getId());
> daoSession.insert(order);
>
> Listorders2 = customer.getOrders();
> // size1 == orders2.size(); // NOT updated
> // orders1 == orders2; // SAME list object
> ```
>
> Likewise, you can delete related entities:
>
> ```
> List orders = customer.getOrders(); daoSession.delete(newOrder);
> orders.remove(newOrder);
> ```
>
> Sometimes, it may be cumbersome or even impossible to update all
>   to-many relations manually after related entities were added or
>   removed. To the rescue, greenDAO has reset methods to clear the cached
>   list. If a to-many relation may have changed potentially, you can
>   force greenDAO to reload the list of related entities:
>
> ```
> customer.resetOrders();
> List orders2 = customer.getOrders();
> ```

Try to reset your relations when you add or remove elements.